# Full path in the menu

Tags: routes, uri

I've trying to setup a Drupal 7 site where I already have some content added. The content is bound to a multi-level menu, but the path's for nodes in the submenus show only the actual node's alias, omitting the parent nodes. I wish to have url's where the path contains the content structure, no matter how many levels are?

I have tried a few [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) settings:

- `[node:menu-link:parents:join-path]/[node:title]`
- `[node:menu-link:parent:url:path]`

After each try, I have rebuilt the paths and cleared cache, but I am still not getting the paths that I need, and they haven't actually changed.  All of my nodes have the "Generate automatic URL alias" setting checked on the node edit page.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: btw, I could enter anything there manually? like with /(slashes) and stuff. I thought there should be some black magic applied to the path so it would look for all branches in the menu tree and join them together

Comment: I integrated our comments into the original question; edit if anything is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I really should have known what pathauto is, but I've got this drupal install already configured, and I am not sure what features are from what modules and what modules are included in this setting. (there are too many with really too many features)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following.

Take a backup of the database. [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) makes this easy.

Make sure core and modules are up to date, especially Pathauto and Token.

Browse to admin/config/search/path/patterns, and set the path pattern to `[node:menu-link:parents:join-path]/[node:menu-link]`.  Credit to [Menu path in Pathauto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683610/menu-path-in-pathauto).

Browse to admin/config/search/path and delete the bad aliases, or admin/config/search/path/delete_bulk and just delete all the content aliases.  Be careful here, and make sure you have a backup.

Spot check a few nodes, and make sure the "Generate automatic URL alias" is set.

Double check that the nodes have a menu entry set on the node edit page, and that the parent is correct.

Double check the menus and make sure that the links have the paths set to `node/XXX`.  You need to click the EDIT link to see this.

Browse to admin/config/search/path/update_bulk to create all of the aliases for the existing nodes.

Clear Drupal cache from admin/config/development/performance

That should work.

Comment: Thank you, this really worked as I imagined. Is the deletion of previos aliases always necessary?

Comment: Yes, it usually is.  Old aliases are kept around by default in case they get out into the wild.  This prevents 404s when someone uses the old URL to access a n aliased page.

Comment: Path pattern is using the following invalid tokens: [node:menu-link:parents:join-path].

Answer (score 0):

you can change the url path to the other site by going to Structure,menus,under main menu--click list of links. .click the edit and click the page u want to change the url and lastly put it in PATH and done..